# Setup a global loading animation istead on every div. Javascript - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I setup a global loading instead on every div? The loading pic appears until all pages are loaded.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#termid').change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#firstresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + '.php', function(){$('#firstresult').removeClass('loading') });
    $('#secondresult').empty().addClass('loading').load(val + 'b.php', function(){$('#secondresult').removeClass('loading') });

    });
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when the entire function ends*? Which function? You are trigerring two parallel AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't understand - the code you have removes the `.loading` class when the file is loaded in.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov Hi, when all the ajax calls end ... when the loading is end.

Comment: @NeXXeuS Is there a way to have 1 loading image instead of 2 ? There is a loading for firstresult and another one for secondresult div. My purpose is to have 1 loading image for all divs.

Comment: Can you use the global ajax callbacks .ajaxStart() and .ajaxComplete()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$().ajaxStart(function(){
    // add a loading div
    $(body).append($("<div id='loading'>loading...</div>"));
}).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // remove loading div
    $("#loading").remove();
});
```

Comment: As long as it is after where you include the jQuery library, wherever really. Are you experiencing problems?